# Types of argument to be passed to <? super T> in Java

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, supertype, pecs

In Chapter 8 of Generic Types from Core Java Volume I Edition 10,

> NOTE: Another common use for supertype bounds is an argument type of a
>   functional interface. For example, the Collection interface has a method
>
> `default boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)`
>
> The method removes all elements that fulfill the given predicate. For example,
>   if you hate employees with odd hash codes, you can remove them like this:
>
> `ArrayList<Employee> staff = . . .;
>   Predicate<Object> oddHashCode = obj -> obj.hashCode() %2 != 0;
>   staff.removeIf(oddHashCode);`
>
> You want to be able to pass a `Predicate<Object>`, not just a `Predicate<Employee>`. The
>   super wildcard makes that possible.

I met some problems when trying to understand this, so `<? super E>` means that filter could point to any predicate type that can be superclass of `Employee` or `Employee` itself.

The text above mentioned we could pass a `Predicate<Object>` to `Predicate<? super E>`.

But what if `Predicate<? super E>` points to `Predicate<Employee>`, can `Predicate<Object>` be passed to `Predicate<Employee>`?

Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. For example, a function that takes `Predicate<? super Employee>` (as in your `ArrayList<Employee>` example) can also accept a `Predicate<Object>` like [`Objects::nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull(java.lang.Object)). Conceptually, this makes sense for the following reason: "We (the class) take a `Predicate` that operates on us, or on any of the (transitive) superclasses of ourself, because we have an *is-a* relationship with those superclasses." That is to say, a function that takes any `Object` and returns a `boolean` is equivalently applicable to `Employee` because `Employee` *is-a* `Object`, and so it is valid to apply this function to `Employee`. The derived class is not the exact same as the base class, but the predicate (logical test) still applies to the derived class, because it makes sense to talk about the derived class as-a base class.

Let's go through an example: `Employees` could be derived from `Person`. If 
`Person` can be tested with a `Predicate<Person>` called `hasJob`, then it is logically sound to be able to test `Employees` for `hasJob` as well. The ability of that function to take `Predicate<? super Employee>` instead of just `Predicate<Employee>` is required to maintain the ability of the function to take a logically sound predicate. On the other hand, if you only expect for `Employee`s to be tested for some property, you might accept only a `Predicate<Employee>` instead, because that corresponds to the logical soundness of only `Employee` and its derived classes possessing the ability to be tested for that property.

To be 100% clear about what is going on here:

- `Predicate<? super Employee>` accepts `Predicate` that `test`s `Employee` and *any superclass* of `Employee`, **including** `Object`
- `Predicate<Employee>` accepts `Predicate` that `test`s `Employee` and *any subclass* of `Employee`, which **excludes** `Object`

Given this class hierarchy: `SalariedEmployee is-a Employee is-a Person`, here's what happens (P is shorthand for `Predicate`):

```
╔══════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════╗
║       Type       ║ P<Person> ║ P<? super Person> ║ P<Employee> ║ P<? super Employee> ║ P<SalariedEmployee> ║ P<? super SalariedEmployee> ║
╠══════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════╣
║ Person           ║ Accept    ║ Accept            ║ Reject      ║ Accept              ║ Reject              ║ Accept                      ║
║ Employee         ║ Accept    ║ Reject            ║ Accept      ║ Accept              ║ Reject              ║ Accept                      ║
║ SalariedEmployee ║ Accept    ║ Reject            ║ Accept      ║ Reject              ║ Accept              ║ Accept                      ║
║ Object           ║ Reject    ║ Accept            ║ Reject      ║ Accept              ║ Reject              ║ Accept                      ║
╚══════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════╝
```

Note that `Accept/Reject` denote the types that can be fed into the `Predicate`, not the actual result of the `Predicate`.

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/10661805 , in "Consumer Super" situation, it said we can only add `Employee` or subclass of `Employee` to the writing method (I supposed writing method is any method that consumes argument) of a `<? super T>` type. So I am quite confused when in fact we can add supertype of T into the method. I think I have messed up the idea.

Comment: @HolmesQueen Remember, in `removeIf`, you're consuming a `Predicate`, not producing anything. Therefore, you use `? super E`. You don't know what type the `Predicate` will take, except that it must take `E`. This is equivalent to saying that the `Predicate` will take `E` or any superclass of `E`, which is exactly what `Predicate<? super E>` means.

Comment: Writing is **NOT** consuming!!! Writing is *producing* values, reading/processing is *consuming* values!

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52468735/10661805, so we are actually just assigning the values without even writing them? If we have an adding method, does this statement (`Predicate<? super Employee>` accepts `Predicate` that `test`s `Employee` and *any superclass* of `Employee`, **including** `Object`) still work?

Comment: Well, we're not really assigning, except in the sense that the value of `Predicate<? super Employee>` provided to the `removeIf` method is assigned to some inner variable within the method. The "assigning" within the answer you've linked indicates which types of `List` can be set to the wildcard `List`, whereas the get/add columns refer to the types that can be used as parameters/return types from those methods. Do recall that all lists are parameterized with an `E` (`List<E>`), so the `get` method returns an `E` and `add` method takes an `E`.

Comment: Talking about `add`/`get` doesn't really make sense in the context of the generic parameter for `removeIf`, because `removeIf` takes a predicate on `E` and its superclasses, whereas `get` returns `E` (that can be assigned to any superclass of `E` as per normal reference assignment rules) and `add` takes `E` (which is any subclass of `E` as per the same reference assignment rules`).

Comment: Refer to the link again, so if we have `List<? super A>`, we could just add A and its subclasses but not its superclass like `Object`. I still don't understand why we can add an `Object` type into `<? super T>`. Does the `add` method in the link reflect the problems I met or actually these two things are completely different stuff? After viewing your answer, so I just assume it's like an assignment operation (which is not really assigning according to you) and it's definitely not a `get/add` method.

Comment: If you check the top answer in that question, you'll see that you can't add an `Object` type into `<? super T>`. The reason given is: `You can't add any object to List<? extends T> because you can't guarantee what kind of List it is really pointing to, so you can't guarantee that the object is allowed in that List. The only "guarantee" is that you can only read from it and you'll get a T or subclass of T.` And yes, `removeIf` is nothing like an `add/get` method. With regards to inserting `Object` into `<? super T>`, you can add instances of `T` or its subclasses, but NOT its superclasses.

Comment: That is to say, inserting `Object` into a `List<? super T>` only works if you have `T` as a superclass/same class of `Object` (inserting `Object` into `List<? super Object>` will work, inserting `Object` into `List<? super Employee>` will not work).

Comment: Yeah, but I should never mix the `Predicate` scenario with inserting/wrtiting method, right? It's merely an assignment but not an inserting/writing process. If so, that really clears my doubt.

Comment: Well, it can get complicated. What if you have a `List<Predicate<Employee>>`? Then `removeIf` would be `boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super Predicate<Employee>> filter)` as its method signature, `add` would be `boolean add(Predicate<Employee> e)`, and `get` would be `Predicate<Employee> get(int index)`. You can see how the `Predicate` is nested in `removeIf`, because it's a predicate on the element type of the `List`. In any case, you shouldn't be worrying about complicated generics most of the time, since the standard library handles a *lot* of the complexities out of the box.